# Using "&" character in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Anyway to get around using "&" in a query? When I try this query, an undefined variable error is returned.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT model FROM carval_data WHERE make = 'A&W' ORDER BY CAST(model AS CHAR)"
```

EDIT: Just figured out it's not an issue with MySQL, but rather PHP. Any solutions?

Second EDIT: This is what's returned

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/var/www/html/carval.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br /><br />

<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: query in <b>/var/www/html/carval.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query(): Empty query in <b>/var/www/html/carval.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in <b>/var/www/html/carval.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
```

Here's the lines 32-50

```
foreach($body as $key => $jsons) { 
    foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'query'){
            $query = $value;
        }
    }
}

mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if($result === FALSE){
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}

if (!$query) {
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: CHAR(38)      use the CONCAT() function for more predictable results

Comment: Your query is perfectly valid for MySQL 5.6. See example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a649a/2. Perhaps your PHP or similar script has a variable that is undefined.

Comment: Yes, just figured that out. I guess it's an issue with my php. Any way to fix that?

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message and what does the code look like around the line indicated?

Comment: ..and the code from `carval.php`, lines 33 - 44? Do you think we can guess just from error messages alone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Let us know the php code.

Comment: It works for every other variable I use though. It only fails with "A&W." Is there no escape character for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHAR(38)      use the CONCAT() function for more predictable results.    also test your answer in a query window and then in the .Net C# (or whatever) library.  You may find your problem is not at the raw SQL level but the client library.